# In azure where do I add an email endpoint for sending results from azure automation runbook?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-eventgrid

I have runbook created in azure automation for getting the list of Vm's running. I want to know if there is a way to add a email endpoint for sending the response of this runbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send directly from Azure Automation natively, you will need to either use SendGrid or a Logic App to send the email.

### SendGrid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-send-email

### Logic App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet